# Need help to create a Laravel DB table for vedic astrology match making form(compatibilty)

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

I want to have a form where I will be comparing a person A birth details with a few other prospective(probaby upto 5) opposite gender birth details to check their compatibility as per vedic astrology.

First form field set will include fields to be captured for primary person birth details(dob-date of birth, tob-time of birth, pob-place of birth.

Second field set is where I would like to provide options to capture details of upto five persons where they have to provide name and other date/time/place of birth details however it is not mandatory that all five matching partner details will be provided in every entry. I am not sure how to manage empty fields if the visitor only provides primary person details and only two or three matching partner details in the form and leaves rest of the addtional person detail fields empty.

```
here is my db structure
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->string('gender');
            $table->date('dob');  //date of birth
            $table->time('tob');    //time of birth
            $table->string('pob');  //place of birth
            $table->string('comments');
//above is for primaruy partner

//details for matching partner 1
            $table->string('nameone');
            $table->string('genderone');
            $table->date('dobone'); //date of birth
            $table->time('tobone'); //time of birth
            $table->string('pobone');   //place of birth
            $table->string('comone');
            $table->string('commentsone');
    
//details for matching partner 2
            $table->string('nametwo');
            $table->string('gendertwo');
            $table->date('dobtwo');
            $table->time('tobtwo');
            $table->string('pobtwo');
            $table->string('comtwo');
            $table->string('commentstwo');

//details for matching partner 3
            $table->string('namethree');
            $table->string('genderthree');
            $table->date('dobthree');
            $table->time('tobthree');
            $table->string('pobthree');
            $table->string('comthree');
            $table->string('commentsthree');

//details for matching partner 4
            $table->string('namefour');
            $table->string('genderfour');
            $table->date('dobfour');
            $table->time('tobfour');
            $table->string('pobfour');
            $table->string('comfour');
            $table->string('commentsfour');

//details for matching partner 5
            $table->string('namefive');
            $table->string('genderfive');
            $table->date('dobfive');
            $table->time('tobfive');
            $table->string('pobfive');
            $table->string('comfive');
            $table->string('commentsfive');

            $table->timestamps();
            $table->index('user_id');
```

Comment: This is a very broad question and shows no indication of what you have already tried. We are here to help you but not to do the work for you! Have a go at designing and implementing your form and DB table and come back to us if you have specific problems. Good Luck!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have indeed prepared the DB table but my question is how do I control not null in those fields, not every time my users may fill details of all 5 matching partners, in such instance how do I avoid getting error in DB when submitting empty fields from those additional input sets?

Comment: You make sure there are values submitted, or you allow the columns to be nullable.

Comment: There is an open-source project in Github, that does something very similar to what you want todo.
https://github.com/gen-so/Genso.Astrology/blob/e6965fcb002c49ed1f32b54745ca1c4c7f20603e/Library/managers/MatchCalculator.cs

Answer (score -1):

As per my thinking ...

you need to follow below steps

1. First of all you need to list out database table and field as rough work
2. you need to create migration with Laravel database migration https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations
3. you need to run those created migrations which will generate table and its fields in database automatic.

I hope you get your desire answer.